# (node:15893) DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm developing a backend for a REST API. It uses MongoDB as a database. I am using MongoDB 5.3.3.

I would like to remove a collection of items, upon API request, but received the above error message:

> DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead

How do I completely drop the collection?

Comment: Error is self explanatory, just use one of those method mentioned instead of remove().

Comment: Hi, a reason that you probably received downvotes is that in StackOverflow, people expect that you indicate what you tried so far, and how it didn't work, so we can get a better idea as to exactly what you wanted to accomplish. I assume that deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite did not work out for you or you maybe didn't understand them? Either way you should explain a bit more what you want to accomplish and what you tried so far, and why you think that didn't work.

Comment: What does "(node:15893)" refer to?

Answer (score 21):

Instead of: Model.remove({});
Use: Model.deleteMany({});

Comment: if using mongoshell, one can use: db.<collectionname>.deleteMany({}). It will return something like this: { acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 24 }. Deleted count can wary. it was 24 in my case.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me when I wanted to drop a specific collection is:

```
mongoose.connection.dropCollection(specificCollection.name)
// or you could use the collection's name exactly such as 'user'
```

The `mongoose.connection.dropCollection()` method takes in the exact name for a collection which you probably defined when you made the schema.

Probably, the specific model you have defined somewhere in your code is something like:

```
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Note that it is case insensitive, `'User'` is the same as `'user'`.

Comment: It says in their question: “I would like to remove a collection of items”  if they say remove a collection that would suggest they do want to drop a whole collection. Also they used the plural, “items” which suggests more than one item not a single document but many documents. What gives you the opposite impression?

Answer (score 0):

Use deleteOne or deleteMany accordingly.
I have used **deleteOne()** instead of **remove()** function to delete items from delete api from mongodb collections. It worked for me.

```
app.delete('/todo/:item', function(req, res){   
  Todo.find({item: req.params.item.replace(/\-/g, " ")}).deleteOne(function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
      res.json(data);   
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs in new versions of [Mongoose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoose_%28web_server%29). If you want to use Model.remove() method, you should change the current Mongoose version to "mongoose": "^5.10.14" or lower. Read more information about it at *[Deprecation Warnings](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html)*.